# MS Word: Changing the template, depending on the print paper

Tags: templates, printing, ms-word

I have this situation in the office. We have A4 paper and letter paper. The letter paper has a logo of the company already printed, but not the A4.

How could I make a template that shows the logo if the print is in normal paper, but hides it if its in letter paper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of printer do you use? If the printer driver has a watermark feature that supports images, you could create two print queues
 (1) Letter papersize + No Watermark
 (2) A4 papersize + Watermark
And use the appropriate queue when you send the print job (Queue 1 for letter job and Queue 2 for A4 job)

Hope this helps. If so +1 :)

Comment: Another option is to use VBA. Here are some links. You will need to add extra code for checking what the paper size is but that should be do-able. - (1) http://vbaexcel.eu/vba-macro-code/insert-image-to-word-resize-image-insert-borders-using-vba-excel (2) http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/03/adding-images-to-header-using-vba-word.html

Comment: The problem is I know nothing about macros. How do I make the code run? Is there something like an "onPrint" event?

Comment: this is an initial reference for getting started with Macros - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604039.aspx . Regarding when to run, probably it can run when you open the file itself. Else you can go to the Macros tab and explicitly run it